# Plot looks different everytime i run the code

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, math, scipy

I have a problem with my code. It looks different everytime i run it. Any ideas? I don't see any problem. I am looking at this code since 2h and I can't find the problem...

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import stats


x = np.arange(0,24, 1)
y = stats.poisson.pmf(x, mu=13)
a =stats.poisson.rvs(mu=13, size=5000)

#plt.stem(a,x)
plt.hist(a,bins=x,density=True,edgecolor="red")
plt.title("Poisson Verteilung mit Erwartungswert 13")
plt.xlabel("Anzahl M.")
plt.ylabel("Wahrscheinlichkeit")
"""
i=10
o=30
while i != o:
  if y[i]*100<0.5:
    #print(i)
    break
  i+=1
"""

#plot to specific x value
plt.xlim(0, 23)

plt.plot()
plt.plot(13, y[13], marker='x', markersize=5, color="black",label="Varianz")
plt.plot(13, y[13], marker='x', markersize=5, color="black",label="Median")
plt.legend(loc="upper left")
```

Comment: If you use this code `a =stats.poisson.rvs(mu=13, size=5000)`, you obtain random numbers described probability mass function for poisson procces.  So, you choose const mu, but if you call this code again values of distribution are changed. More useful information you could find in [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.poisson.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using [random statistical distribution](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/stats.html), each time you run your code a new random distribution is created.
In order to get repeatability (your code picks always the same random distribution when you run it) you have to [set a seed](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.random.seed.html) at the beginning of your code:

```
np.random.seed(42)
```

You can choose which seed you prefer, 42 is a common one.

### Complete Code

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import stats


np.random.seed(42)
x = np.arange(0,24, 1)
y = stats.poisson.pmf(x, mu=13)
a =stats.poisson.rvs(mu=13, size=5000)

#plt.stem(a,x)
plt.hist(a,bins=x,density=True,edgecolor="red")
plt.title("Poisson Verteilung mit Erwartungswert 13")
plt.xlabel("Anzahl M.")
plt.ylabel("Wahrscheinlichkeit")
"""
i=10
o=30
while i != o:
  if y[i]*100<0.5:
    #print(i)
    break
  i+=1
"""

#plot to specific x value
plt.xlim(0, 23)

plt.plot()
plt.plot(13, y[13], marker='x', markersize=5, color="black",label="Varianz")
plt.plot(13, y[13], marker='x', markersize=5, color="black",label="Median")
plt.legend(loc="upper left")

plt.show()
```

### Plot

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much!!

One additional question. Do you know how I can fit my Poisson distribution to a plot with „plt.stem“ ?

Comment: You have to get bins positions and heights with `heights, positions, _ = plt.hist(a,bins=x,density=True,edgecolor="red")`; then edit positions like this `positions = [position - 0.5 for position in positions if position != positions[0]]` in order to center the stems; finally plot the stem: `plt.stem(positions, heights, linefmt = 'C1-', markerfmt = 'C1o')`. Please, open another question if you need help on this particular topic